# Attribute begin with selector not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

The `div[class^="kooy-"]` not working. At the same time `div[class^="kooy"]` gives the result as expected.

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid skyblue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
div[class^="kooy-"] {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="kooy kooy-tomato">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod a, nihil culpa rerum vero esse facilis sint voluptatem eius. Placeat, repudiandae, accusantium. Tempora, tempore ea pariatur molestias culpa quia id.</div>

<div class="kooy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, eius illum. Adipisci pariatur, harum soluta inventore nihil cupiditate dolores ab cum ullam fugit amet, quae provident fuga ea dolorem nobis.</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you switch your classes round it seems to work:

```
<div class="kooy-tomato kooy">
```

It seems that `div[class^="kooy-"]` is only able to find the first class and does not look for a second class on an element like a `<div>` as the `^` only looks at the first item within the attribute

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLxbcLyr/)

How ever if you try `div[class*="kooy-"]` The `*` Looks at what is contained within the attribure

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLxbcLyr/1/)

If you want to know a bit more about the [CSS attribure selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't work because `class="kooy kooy-tomato"` doesn't start with `kooy-` but with `kooy` . Instead, you can use the `attribute contains selector` (`[attr*=value]`).

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid skyblue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
div[class*="kooy-"] {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="kooy kooy-tomato">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod a, nihil culpa rerum vero esse facilis sint voluptatem eius. Placeat, repudiandae, accusantium. Tempora, tempore ea pariatur molestias culpa quia id.</div>

<div class="kooy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, eius illum. Adipisci pariatur, harum soluta inventore nihil cupiditate dolores ab cum ullam fugit amet, quae provident fuga ea dolorem nobis.</div>
```

Comment: But still I don't understand **why** begin with not working !

Comment: Begin is working. But the value doesn't begin with "kooy-". It begins with "kooy". The answer modifies the selector from matching a value that begins (`^`) to contains (`*`). https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Comment: Exactly as Michael said, if you change order of classes then it will work https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1084/

Comment: You are using attribute selector so you need to look at class as attribute and in your case it doesn't start with `kooy-`.